# Bypassing redirect based on URL (again)

Tags: java, wordpress, redirect

I know that variations of this question have been asked but I have yet to be able to implement any code that successfully works, so kindly forgive any redundancy. My restaurant used a third party to produce a mobile app and menu on cel phones, etc. To accomplish this, on my wordpress site, I have inserted the following (specified by third party) code in the header.php section:

```
<script src='http://s.singleplatform.com/js/mobile_redirect.js'></script>
<script>

    if(document.referrer)
    {
        if(document.referrer.indexOf('m.singlepage') == -1) redirect_mobile_browser(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,'http://www.singlepage.com/victorys-banner/menu');
    }
    else
     redirect_mobile_browser(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,'http://www.singlepage.com/victorys-banner/menu');
</script>
```

But like others who have asked, I only want www.victorysbanner.com (or victorysbanner.com) to land on the mobile site, but for other URLs, for example, www.victorysbanner.com/about, I want to bypass the call to the mobile site and go to the actual URL. I have tried various if statements but just can't make it happen. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Pradhan Balter

Answer (score 0):

try putting

```
if(document.URL == "http://www.victorysbanner.com/") {redirect code}
```

around your code. you may need to add

```
|| document.URL == "http://victorysbanner.com/"
```

if your webpage can be accessed with or without the www.